# Python: try-except block for sum function with 2 arguments

Tags: python, return, try-except

I have a sum function which takes two values as input, and returns the sum. However, I need to raise an exception if either one of them is not of type `int` or `float`.

My attempt:

```py
def add(a, b):
    
    try:
        return a+b
    except:
        raise TypeError("{0} is invalid".format(a))
    except:
        raise TypeError("{0} is invalid".format(b))
```

returns:

```py
SyntaxError: default 'except:' must be last
```

Is `return` in the wrong place?

Comment: The `except:` block is executed if an exception is raised in the `try` block. What do you think having a second `except:` block does?

Comment: They do the same thing, but print an error message related to the value that caused the exception - at least this was my intention.

Comment: How would the running program know which `except:` it was supposed to execute? They are declared identically.

Comment: the second `except` can never be reached (hence the SyntaxError) - python looks for the first matching except block and executes it

Answer (score 0):

the better form of writing such a thing is in this way:

```
def add(a, b):
    if type(a) != int and type(a) != float:
        raise TypeError("{0} is invalid".format(a))
    if type(b) != int and type(b) != float:
        raise TypeError("{0} is invalid".format(b))
    return a+b
```

and use *try* and *catch* in where you call this function

Comment: `type(a) != int or type(a) != float` is always true.

Comment: @khelwood yes right, thanks for correction